# Editing Fragment UI items with AsynTask

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm working on an Android application that finds the computers on local network. It using **AsynTask** in background to discover that devices, i'm also using **fragment** pages to show results. The problem is i'm not able to make AsyncTask to edit fragment items. How can i handle it

Comment: Now if only you had added some code, we'd have a clue what you are actually doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use interface for interaction between AsyncTask and your fragment:

```
interface TaskListener {
    void onTaskComplete(Data data);
}
```

implement fragment ... TaskListener

```
class YourFragment implements TaskListener {
// your fragment code is here

    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(Data data) {
        //this method will call from AsyncTask
        //update your fragment ui here
    }
}
```

assign the TaskListener to the AsyncTask in Constructor

```
public AsycTask(TaskListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

call the onTaskComplete in "onPostExecute" method of AsyncTask:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Data data) {
    listener.onTaskComplete(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the activity which created the fragment can access the fragment. Create a function in the activity which changes the elements in the fragment. Then call that function from the AsyncTask and pass along any information the fragment will need in the parameters of the function.